# When should I accept an answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

So far, I have a 100% accept rate.  I think I might be slightly overreacting to some peoples' 40% or 50% rates.  I want to know if it's [considered impolite (note the first comment)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/in-chess-why-is-1-e4-e5-2-nf3-nc6-3-bb5-a6-4-bxc6-rarely-visited/3972#3972) to accept an answer too quickly.  Also, is it ever appropriate just to never accept an answer?  When should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I can add much to the standard stackexchange [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/151694) except to emphasize that quickly accepting the first correct answer can lower the odds of someone writing a more thorough, thoughtful answer later.  In most cases I think waiting two days gives folks plenty of time to write that longer answer if they are going to.